# Error:Could not initialize class org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.strategy.StaticVersionComparator

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-2.0

I can not build project and every time I try below error is appear,

> Error:Could not initialize class
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.strategy.StaticVersionComparator

this is my gradle :

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'

 }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the latest gradle and changed my gradle, so problem solved, but of course its not the best solution! 
sorry of my bad English.